# Exit For Loop in Robot Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, robotframework

Using Robot Framework, I am trying to create a FOR loop in which a random value is selected from the list. After the random value is selected, the page for that value is opened, then I want to do validate the data available for that party, etc. And then the loop should exit if the value is matched.

Currently, I'm able to select a random value and go to that value page but not able to perform further actions as the scripts fail as the FOR loop finds another value from the list.

```
@{ORGANISATIONAL_NAME}  JSK MARKETING  KEDARNATH COMOTRADE  PONDICHERRY SRI LAKSHMI

View Basic Info of the Party
    ${value} =  Evaluate  random.choice($ORGANISATIONAL_NAME)  random
    input text  ${SEARCH_BAR}  ${value}
    log to console  \nvalue: ${value}
    click element  ${SEARCH_BUTTON}
    log  ${value}
    Run Keyword If  '${value}' == 'JSK MARKETING'  click element  ${JSK_MARKETING}
     ...  ELSE IF  '${value}' == 'KEDARNATH COMOTRADE'  click element  ${KEDARNATH_COMOTRADE}
     ...  ELSE IF  '${value}' == 'PONDICHERRY SRI LAKSHMI'  click element  ${PONDICHERRY_SHRI_LAKSHMI}
     ...  ELSE  log to console  condition didn't met
    FOR  ${value}  IN  @{ORGANISATIONAL_NAME}
        log to console  ${value}
        click element  ${BASIC_INFO}
        wait until page contains  Summary
        Exit For Loop If  '${value}' == 'JSK MARKETING'
        click element  ${BASIC_INFO}
        wait until page contains  Summary
        Exit For Loop If  '${value}' == 'KEDARNATH COMOTRADE'
        click element  ${BASIC_INFO}
        wait until page contains  Summary
        Exit For Loop If  '${value}' == 'PONDICHERRY SRI LAKSHMI'
    END
```

The validations need to be performed over the selected random value from the list.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @WojtekT The error is that first, it's taking the value say **PONDICHERRY SRI LAKSHMI** and when the **FOR** loop executes it takes another value say **JSK MARKETING** [link](https://ibb.co/7RG3t5n)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you first select a random value.
And then you iterate the list in the order in which it was created.

What is the reason for the for loop?
Because I don't understand what you're trying to do in the loop

EDIT:

If only those 3 values ​​are going to exist on your list you could do this:

```
View Basic Info Of The Party
    ${value} =  Evaluate  random.choice($ORGANISATIONAL_NAME)  random
    Input Text  ${SEARCH_BAR}  ${value}
    Log To Console  \nvalue: ${value}
    Click Element  ${SEARCH_BUTTON}
    Log  ${value}
    Run Keyword If  '${value}' == 'JSK MARKETING'  Click Element  ${JSK_MARKETING}
    ...  ELSE IF    '${value}' == 'KEDARNATH COMOTRADE'  Click Element  ${KEDARNATH_COMOTRADE}
    ...  ELSE IF    '${value}' == 'PONDICHERRY SRI LAKSHMI'  Click Element  ${PONDICHERRY_SHRI_LAKSHMI}
    Log To Console  ${value}
    Click Element  ${BASIC_INFO}
    Wait Until Page Contains  Summary
```

If you are going to have more values ​​in the list and you only want to perform an action in one of those 3 cases try to do this:

```
View Basic Info Of The Party
    ${value} =  Evaluate  random.choice($ORGANISATIONAL_NAME)  random
    Input Text  ${SEARCH_BAR}  ${value}
    Log To Console  \nvalue: ${value}
    Click Element  ${SEARCH_BUTTON}
    Log  ${value}
    Run Keyword If  '${value}' == 'JSK MARKETING'  Click Element  ${JSK_MARKETING}
    ...  ELSE IF    '${value}' == 'KEDARNATH COMOTRADE'  Click Element  ${KEDARNATH_COMOTRADE}
    ...  ELSE IF    '${value}' == 'PONDICHERRY SRI LAKSHMI'  Click Element  ${PONDICHERRY_SHRI_LAKSHMI}
    ...  ELSE  Log To Console  condition didn\'t met
    Run Keyword If  '${value}' == 'JSK MARKETING' or '${value}' == 'KEDARNATH COMOTRADE' or '${value}' == 'PONDICHERRY SRI LAKSHMI'     Run Keywords
    ...  Log To Console  ${value}   AND
    ...  Click Element  ${BASIC_INFO}   AND
    ...  Wait Until Page Contains  Summary
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The reason to use the for loop is that after selecting a random value I want to perform data validation on that particular party. The whole scenario is that I've got a huge dataset of different parties and the data for every party is also different. Now I've to select a random party from that dataset and validate it.

Comment: Tried both the codes and now it's failing directly after searching for the party because now it jumps to **Click Element  ${BASIC_INFO}** rather thank clicking the party first i.e **'${value}' == 'KEDARNATH COMOTRADE'  Click Element  ${KEDARNATH_COMOTRADE}**. [link] (https://ibb.co/T1sggF6)

Comment: I think I know what is your problem. Let's focus on code 2.

The last 3 lines contain `...` at the beginning, this is so that the last 3 lines depend on the keyword `Run Keywords` that is at the end of the check (line 11). 

I think you haven't put the `...` at the beginning, and that is why the last 3 lines are always executed.

It can be seen in your log, since the last 3 lines should appear within the Run Keywords key in the log, like this: [link](https://ibb.co/JpVBpZp)

Comment: After reformatting the code the problem still exists. Now what's happening is that after random selection it doesn't click on the party page link, the browser gets closed and the result is a pass. [link] (https://ibb.co/cKBYgh3)

Comment: None of the conditions is met, since pondicherry sri lakshmi jewelery does not match with pondicherry sri lakshmi. The code is correct in this case

Comment: Hi Alberto, the problem still exists. Not able to click on the party link page and perform further actions. (https://ibb.co/D8TVzcv)

Comment: The code works fine.
`KEDARNATH COMOTRADE` is different from `KEDARNATH COMMOTRADE`

Check the comparisons

Comment: My bad, I missed that. The test case failed after clicking the party link and the page got redirected to the landing page and was not able to find "Summary" text. (https://ibb.co/zncdg8v)

Comment: I would need to see the html of the page to continue helping you. 
It can happen for several reasons, the page has not been fully loaded, the page contains frames, in this case you must first select the frame before clicking, or simply that the page does not contain any text Summary

Comment: Hi Alberto, here is the code [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vhfkLgmMAXGaJX1LYsrh5u8OB5r43yu0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have reviewed the HTML, in principle it should work. 

The only thing I can think of is that Summary is not on the page when you click on Basic Info